# How do I access a variable value assigned to an HTML.Hidden variable in a MVC Controller Action Method

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am writing my first ASP.Net webpage and using MVC.

I have a string that I am building in a partial view with a grid control (DevExpress MVCxGridView).  In my partial view I am using a HTML.Hidden helper as shown below.

```
    ' Create a hidden variable to pass back a comma-delimited string
Response.Write(Html.Hidden( "exclusionList", Model.ExclusionList))
```

The value of of this hidden element is assigned in client side javaScript:

```
 exclusionListElement = document.getElementById("exclusionList");
 // ... 
 exclusionString = getExclusionString();
 exclusionListElement.value = exclusionString;
```

This seems to work without problem.

In my controller action method:

```
        <AcceptVerbs( HttpVerbs.Post )> _
    Public Function MyPartialCallback(updatedItemList As myModel) As ActionResult

        Dim myData As myModel = GetMyModel()

        Return PartialView( "MyPartial", myModel.myList )
    End Function
```

The updatedItemList parameter is always nothing and exclusion list exists no where in the Request.Forms.

My questions are:

1. What is the correct way to use Html.Hidden so that I can access data in a MVC Controller Action method.
2. Is adding "cargo" variables to Request.Form the best and only way to send data back to a server side MVC Controller Action method?  It just seems like *twine and duct-tape* approach. Is there a more structured approach?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get the `exclusionList` variable back, you just need to add a property to your view model that matches that name exactly.  Make sure it is of the correct type (`string` it looks like in this case) and then it should auto populate that property in the view model for you.

And yes, there is no need for the `Response.Write` call.  Instead just use the `Html.HiddenFor(...)` helper in your view.

Comment: I tried this too - but to no avail.  I think the only way to do this is with an ajax call to a controller method.  Currently in my ascx (partial view) I define an Html.ActionLink that calls a client side function that calls a javaScript function to update the partial and returns true to proceed to a server side controller method.  Since I really don't want a post-back, I need to call a controller method via ajax.  I wonder if Ajax.ActionLink will allow me to call the same javaScript method followed by a controller method (with no return view...)?

Comment: If you are making a call to the server via Ajax, you will need to populate the data object for the request yourself.  That isn't handled by the browser unless you are posting back... or I suppose if you are using a JavaScript framework which handles it for you.  Assuming you are using jQuery, just pass the request an object with a property named `data` and make sure that the properties of your data match your controller action.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the generated HTML. Note down the name attribute of the hidden field. Use this name as action parameter name:

```
Public Function MyPartialCallback(exclusionList As string)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried this suggestion but the result is still that exclusionList = Nothing in the action method.